# What is a shadow exactly, in static analysis of code?

Tags: java, static, code-analysis, analysis

I tried looking for the answer to this! There are a lot of papers that say about Shadows. What is this exactly?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are talking about shadowing with names, the [Java Language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1) says this

> Some declarations may be shadowed in part of their scope by another
>   declaration of the same name, in which case a simple name cannot be
>   used to refer to the declared entity.

and gives this example

```
class Test {
    static int x = 1;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0;
        System.out.print("x=" + x);
        System.out.println(", Test.x=" + Test.x);
    }
}
```

where `x` is a `static` class variable and a local variable. The local variable will be used if `x` is referenced in the method the local variable `x` is defined in. If you wanted to reference the class variable, you would need to use

```
Test.x
```

Analysis tools can find things like this.

Comment: Umm...no I didn't mean the shadows of Scope that occur in languages...but I am talking about the Shadow term that occurs in Program Analysis.

Comment: @ShivamMax Can you link any article that talks about it?

Comment: It actually appears in a lot of Research Papers!

Comment: @ShivamMax If you don't have a reference, I can't help you. I haven't heard of `shadow` in that context.

Comment: Okay...I'll try to link a PDF that says about it! Thanks anyways! :)